# Proyecto compatible con todas las versiones de windows con visual studio 2012 para escritorio (winforms)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms, windows

Buen día acabo de publicar un proyecto con visual studio 2012 para escritorio (winforms), cuando instalo la aplicación en windows 8.1 y 8 no hay problema, pero mi problema es que cuando lo instalo en windows 7, 10 y xp aparecen varios errores. Mi pregunta es, si hay alguna forma de publicar la aplicación de manera que sea compatible con todas las versiones de windows.
Gracias por su atención ;)

Comment: Que tipo de errores?? para que framework lo compilaste?

Comment: en xp: ".exe no es una aplicacion valida para win32"
en 10: error en la instalacion de visual basic powerpacks
en 7: error en la instalacion de visual basic powerpacks

Comment: para framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno.. Vamos por partes...

XP no acepta .net 4.5, solo acepta instalaciones hasta el 4

El resto si no tendria problemas con el target... Pero.. me suena a que no mandaste el framework en tu paquete de instalacion, y por lo tanto no tienes la version requerida para el sistema.

La unica duda que me genera es que en 10 deberia venir, o por lo menos uno mas nuevo. Pero todo puede ser. Estas seguro que se cumplen los requisitos de instalacion y estan bien instalados los frameworks?

Recuerda chequear que tu paquete de instalacion tenga como prerequisito en el destino que el framework este instalado, o en su defecto lo baje y lo instale.

Comment: entonces lo que debo hacer es publicarlo para el framework 4.5 y ya sera compatible con todas las versiones de windows?

Comment: perdon era framework 4*

Comment: exactamente. Pero ten cuidado de siempre verificar los prerequisitos para tu aplicacion

Comment: Complementando un poco la respuesta, debes tener en cuenta si el Sistema operativo es de 32 o 64 bits en la maquina de destino